# CURL: (35) SSL connect error for Ubuntu server

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, ubuntu-server

I'm playing around with installing ubuntu server on VirtualBox and learning my way around linux.  At one point I got the VM working and able to run curl, wget, apt-get and install docker through my company's proxy.  I decided to rebuild it and now I've hit a strange issue.  wget works with https but curl does not.
Curl is coming back with the following error for all https sites:

```
curl -v https://<url>
trying <IPAddress>...
connected to <proxyserver> port <port> (#0)
ALPN, offering http/1.1
cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
successfully set certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /etc/ssls/certs/ca_certificate.crt
CApath: /etc/ssls/certs
TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, client hello (1):
error: 140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

Any idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue is specific to Ubuntu Server 17.10.1.  Have installed Ubuntu server 16.04.4 LTS.